# PostgreSQL function results in inconsistent number of rows when used in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function "experiments.get_random_experiment_group(experiment)" that when called in isolation behaves normally, but when called in a WHERE clause results in zero or more rows being returned.

For example, if I call this function like so:

```
SELECT 
 experiments.get_random_experiment_group('1a8cd547-8de6-4602-9103-3cea12f57365');
```

it will always return 1 of the 2 groups ids associated with that experiment.

But if I do something like this...:

```
SELECT 
 id, 
 experiment_id,
 proportion 
FROM 
 experiments."group" 
WHERE 
 id = experiments.get_random_experiment_group('1a8cd547-8de6-4602-9103-3cea12f57365');
```

I will sometimes get 1 row, 2 rows, or no rows at all.

Why is it behaving as expected in the first case, but not in the second?  Any suggestions as to what's happening?

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION experiments.get_random_experiment_group (experiment uuid)
    RETURNS uuid
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
    $function$
DECLARE
   result uuid;
BEGIN
    WITH 
        CTE 
    AS 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            random() * (SELECT SUM(g.proportion) FROM experiments."group" g WHERE g.experiment_id = experiment) AS r
    )
    SELECT 
        id
    INTO 
        result
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            id, 
            SUM(proportion) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS s,
            r
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                experiments."group" g
            WHERE 
                g.experiment_id = experiment
        ) a 
        CROSS JOIN 
            CTE
    ) q
WHERE 
    s >= r
ORDER BY 
    id
LIMIT 
    1;
return result;
end;
$function$;
```

The purpose of this function is to randomly select a group id for a given experiment id.  The probability of selecting a particular group is given by the “proportion” assigned to that group.

And here are all of the groups associated with the experiment in my example:

| id | experiment_id | proportion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 95cc9e77-3dff-48d9-91cb-3e17c0c24d5a | 1a8cd547-8de6-4602-9103-3cea12f57365 | 0.5 |
| 47469555-88fd-4cec-925f-9cf15b91bca0 | 1a8cd547-8de6-4602-9103-3cea12f57365 | 0.5 |

I am using postgres version 13.4

Comment: Are you aware that the function is executed as many times as there are rows in the table? That's not a good idea.

Comment: When you are doing the second select you are running the function for each row in `experiments."group" `.

Comment: Yes I see that my query is just straight up bad and incoherent.  

I'm still curious, can anyone explain why I am getting different numbers of rows every time I run it?  For example, why would I occasionally get no results at all?

Comment: Well, when each row is compared with a different random value, anything can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function was getting called for each row in the "group" table, and thus returning rows when and only when the group id of that row happened to correspond to the randomly generated id returned by the function call.

Thanks to the commenters for pointing this out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).